# Tensorflow : bucketize a tensor, then produce categorical tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to transform a tensor of a continuous variable, into buckets, then into a categorical tensor (one-hot encoding based on boundaries)

Say I have this

```
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
boundaries = [3.5, 5.5]
```

I want to have the following output:

```
buckets = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
categorical = [[1, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 1]]
```

I am aware of `tf.feature_column.bucketized_column` and `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity`, but I want to use functions on pure tensors, without transforming data into `numeric_column`.

I am also aware of `tf.one_hot` that allows to obtain `categorical` from `buckets`, but no idea on how to obtain `buckets` from the input tensor.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

As said in the question, use `tf.one_hot` to get from buckets to categories, and use `tf.python.ops.math_ops._bucketize` to get the buckets

Comment: Nice revelation of a well-kept secret!

Comment: I had trouble accessing `tf.python.ops` but `tf.raw_ops.Bucketize` worked